# WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId - Minimum supported client / server incorrect?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've just come to use [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the active console session ID.

I need this to work on XP / Server 2003. I'm 99% sure I've used this before successfully on those OS's. I've just checked (with depends.exe) and kernel32.dll exports `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` on those OS's.

However, the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

`Minimum supported client   Windows Vista`

`Minimum supported server   Windows Server 2008`

What's up with that? Am I missing something? Is it safe to use it on XP / Server 2003?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 are no longer supported, so the minimum **supported** client/server is Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008, respectively. A common mistake is, that developers read the information to mean *"introduced in"*. This is not the case.

> Is it safe to use it on XP / Server 2003?

No. Neither Windows XP nor Windows Server 2003 receive bug fixes, or security and feature updates. The documented contract in the MSDN may or may not apply to systems that are no longer supported.

`WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` is available on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, and if you have established that it is good enough for you, you can use it. It's just not safe to do so. You should ask your customers to upgrade to one of the supported client/server OSs.

Comment: The WTS API has been available since Windows 2000.

Comment: "A common mistake is, that developers read the information to mean "introduced in"." I guess I'm guilty of that. That's why I was confused. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it worked for me too in XP SP3 [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432285(v=vs.85).aspx)